# How to use redux-persist with custom middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist, redux-middleware

Using redux-persist 5.10.0.

It's working perfectly after configuring it using the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist):

```
// configureStore.js
// all imports here

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['auth']
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default function configureStore() {
    const store = createStore(
        persistedReducer,
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
        applyMiddleware(axiosMiddleware),
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );

    const persistor = persistStore(store);

    return { store, persistor };
}
```

and:

```
// index.js
// All imports here

const { store, persistor } = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As you can notice from my configureStore.js file, I have a custom middleware for axios. I'm using JWT for authentication. This middleware will be checking for an action constant named `RECEIVE_LOGIN` so it can assign the returned token to the default header of my axios instance:

```
// axiosConfig.js
// imports here
export const axiosMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'RECEIVE_LOGIN') {
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${action.data.token}`;
    }

    return next(action);
}
```

But because of redux-persist, I cannot get my custom type - RECEIVE_LOGIN - from action.type, I'm getting persist/PERSIST and then persist/REHYDRATE instead. I cannot even find my custom type in `action`.

I looked it up but couldn't find any example with a custom middleware.

So my question is, how do I use `redux-persist` alongside my custom middleware?

Comment: could you please explain `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()`?

Comment: @JoeyGough Ah, this is just a little goodie to setup Redux with the Chrome Dev tools. [Learn more about it here](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first issue, your store configuration process is wrong.  You're calling `applyMiddleware` more than once.  Per the Redux FAQ, [calling `applyMiddleware` multiple times sets up multiple middleware chains, which won't work correctly](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#is-it-ok-to-have-more-than-one-middleware-chain-in-my-store-enhancer-what-is-the-difference-between-next-and-dispatch-in-a-middleware-function).

Change it to be `applyMiddleware(axiosMiddleware, thunk)`, and then see what happens.

Comment: It would have been more clear if this function was called `applyMiddlewares` instead.

Comment: Grammatically, it's sort of indistinct and can be used either way - see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257120/middleware-vs-middlewares